Visiting UK office of my US employer
I work in the US on my F1 Visa OPT, my firm has an office in London , UK. Can i visit london on a visitor visa and work from the London office for 2 weeks?

I would expect your firm to advise you as to whether your intended activities in its London office are permitted as a visitor

What nationality are you?
